# Error: unexpected '}' in "}" in R

Tags: r

I am praticing R codes.
When I type

```
sim.clt <- function (m=100,n=10,p=0.25)
{ z = rbinom(m,n,p)
  x = (z-n*p)/sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
  hist(x,prob=T,breaks=20,main=paste("n =",n,”p =”,p))
  curve(dnorm(x),add=T)
}
```

It gives me errors:

```
Error: unexpected input in:

    "  x = (z-n*p)/sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
      hist(x,prob=T,breaks=20,main=paste("n =",n,?
    >   curve(dnorm(x),add=T)
    > }
    Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
    >
```

How to I fix the error? Thank you

Comment: Are you using unicode quotes here? `”p =”,p)`; replace them by `"`

Comment: Press `ESC` and try again

Comment: @sgibb could you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you using unicode characters in your code: `”p =”,p)`.

Replace

```
hist(x,prob=T,breaks=20,main=paste("n =",n,”p =”,p))
```

by

```
hist(x,prob=T,breaks=20,main=paste("n =",n, "p =",p))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used unicode characters, and I replaced it. Apparently, it works. Thank you:)

Comment: @zaq0718: Could you please accept the answer (hit the checkmark) if it solves your problem.