# Duplicated curly bracket in R

Tags: r

I wrote a function in R using the code below: 
when I run it, an error message occurs: 
How does this happen?

```
columnmeans <- funtion(y) {
    nc <- ncol[y]
    means <- numeric(nc)
    for (i in 1:nc) {
        mean[i] <- mean(y[,i])
    }
    mean
}
```

I expect the function to work, but instead I received:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: typo in `funtion`? should be `function`? and it should be `ncol(y)` and `means[i]` not `mean[i]` and return `means`

Comment: In addition, there is a function in the `base` package called `colMeans`

Comment: You inatitialize `means` and work on `mean` ?

Comment: Related post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25889234/680068) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23273022/680068)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in the code above. Here's a working version:

```
columnmeans <- function(y) {
    nc <- ncol(y)
    means <- numeric(nc)
    for (i in 1:nc) {
        means[i] <- mean(y[,i])
    }
    means
}

v <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
columnmeans(v)
[1] 5.5 5.5
```

Your main issues are:

- `funtion` should be `function`
- `ncol[y]` should be `ncol(y)`
- `mean[i]` should be `means[i]`
- `mean` should be `means`

Comment: Helped you out with an upvote @StewartMacdonald ;-)

Comment: It is not about "want to see the world burn", but site rules, if it is typo, then it should be closed as such. Plus it is a duplicate, see my comment with links.